# To show whether the circum radius of the circle is constant.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, problem-solving, puzzle

Given are two circles $\omega_1,\omega_2$ which intersect at points $X,Y$. Let $P$ be an arbitrary point on $\omega_1$. Suppose that the lines $PX,PY$ meet $\omega_2$ again at points $A,B$ respectively. Prove that the circumcircles of all triangles $PAB$ have the same radius.

I can observe that the $\angle P$ and the chord $XY$ remains constant throughout the problem. What are the other key observations that can be noted from the given problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My diagram looks like this:

[image]

Let the centres of circles $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ be $O_1$ and $O_2$ respectively.

Let $\angle XO_1Y$ be $2\alpha$ and $\angle XO_2Y$ be $2\beta$, both of which are constant no matter where $P$ is.

As you have correctly identified, since the angle at the centre is twice the angle at the circumference, $\angle XPY=\alpha$ which is constant.

For the same reason we get that $\angle XBY=\beta$ which is also constant.

Therefore $\angle PXB=180^\circ-\alpha-\beta$ and so $\angle AXB=180^\circ-\angle PXB=\alpha+\beta$.

Once again due to angle at the centre is twice the angle at the circumference, we get that $\angle AO_2B=\frac12(\alpha+\beta)$.

$O_2A=O_2B$ is the radius of $\omega_2$ and so is constant, and $\angle AO_2B=\frac12(\alpha+\beta)$ is also constant, so all possible triangles $AO_2B$ are congruent, which means that length $AB$ is constant.

Using the full sine rule, we get that $$2R=\frac{AB}{\sin\alpha}$$ where $R$ is the circumradius of triangle $PAB$, but since length $AB$ and $\alpha$ are constant no matter where $P$ is, we get that the circumcircles of all triangles $PAB$ have the same radius.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer @ Sai Mehta.  Could you please share from where did you draw such clean figure ? Thank you.

Comment: geogebra.org/geometry